# Understanding Perf Tool Output

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I recently installed Perf tool On my platform and wanted to use it for profiling my platform. I started profiling a standalone application.Below command I used

perf start ./helloworld

Performance counter stats for './helloworld':

```
  4.555957 task-clock                #    0.000 CPUs utilized
         1 context-switches          #    0.219 K/sec
         0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
       124 page-faults               #    0.027 M/sec
       <not supported> cycles
       <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend
       <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend
       <not supported> instructions
       <not supported> branches
       <not supported> branch-misses

       60.005519331 seconds time elapsed
```

Now I am not sure how should I interpretate this output.is it expected output?

Also,what should I make of < not supported > filed here,Is there anything I need to enable to support this filed before run the command?

Answer (score 3):

Search for "Performance Events" in dmesg output.  It might be disabled.

For instance, on my machine, I have this>>

```
Performance Events: SandyBridge events, Intel PMU driver.
PEBS disabled due to CPU errata.
CPUID marked event: 'cpu cycles' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'instructions' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'bus cycles' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'cache references' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'cache misses' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'branch instructions' unavailable
CPUID marked event: 'branch misses' unavailable
```

Comment: What is exact name of your CPU?

Answer (score 2):

The  lines indicate that your running kernel is missing support for the particular functionality perf needs to profile those aspects of your program. Since most of perf is in kernelspace, you need to ensure your kernel supports the features you need.

EDIT:

When it comes to enabling those features in your kernel, it depends. Unless those components have been compiled as kernel modules, you need to compile them yourself. If they are compiled as modules, you can just `modprobe` them. Try:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -regex .*perf.*
```

If a list appears, try `modprobe`ing each of the module names. Otherwise, you need to compile the modules yourself or the entire kernel yourself.

Comment: Thanks , I guess you're right but any Idea how do I enable those enable support from Linux,Do I enable it at build time or kernel or what?

Comment: Cypher I couldn't find modules related to perf(find . -name *.ko | grep perf).Would please point me out How can I compile these modules.Any Hint would be good enough .

Comment: You need to get a suitable version of the kernel sources (from [here](https://www.kernel.org/)) and then enable perf as modules in the kernel configuration. However, if you plan on compiling the modules, you should compile the whole kernel too, and then run everything off the fresh kernel.

Answer (score 0):

"not supported" is usually when kernel does not support perf even if the kernel has perf modules enabled. Or the hardware has not performance counters like some virtualized hardware may be?
If there is no kernel support for perf, you will probably see "not counted"

Comment: i have recently cross compiled perf for ARM, when i execute perf for some kerenel/user threads it was able to give 'stat' output but in case of few threads/process it fails and says <not counted>, when you say not implemented, what should i have to do inside the code to implement/enable them to count stats of that particular process/thread

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you want to profile. Perf doesn't provide an ultimate answer telling you how fast your program is. If you want to measure performance you have to know where to look. For those lines saying , try giving them manually by -e flag. like perf stat -e cycles ./helloworld

Comment: Thanks @ayan for the response ,I tried doing perf stat -e cycles ,but got < not supported > cycles .Also, how do I make sure that I am getting right Output from Perf